# duplicate hdd serial number "152D20337A0C"

Tags: external-hard-drive, serial-number

What is this "152D20337A0C" "serial number" about? I keep finding disks with this "special" serial number. I have 4 of them at home alone. Serial numbers should be unique.

Comment: Where the 4 drives you tried connected external? (either external drives or internal drives with a external adapter)

Comment: Where are you getting the serial number (printed on the drive or identified by the OS)?  How are they connected (interchangeable through a docking station)?  Do all drives connected in this way show the same serial number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the research I have done every instance of that serial number I found of people asking about their problems on the internet appears to be using some kind of external drive (be it a enclosed external drive or a converter device) or did not specify in their post.

It appears that a common SATA to USB controller chip in external drives or adapters overwrites the real serial number of the drive and replaces it with the value `152D20337A0C`. If you looked on the physical drive itself it likely has a different serial number printed on it and if you took the internal drive and connected to it directly with a SATA connection it would also report differently.

(If you are using a internal drive then my theory is totally wrong and I will gladly delete this answer.)

Comment: I found the real serial number of disk drive (the one printed on the drive) when going through SMART attributes.

Comment: @mighq makes sense, a controller chip is unlikely to modify SMART data as it passes through, but a simple query of "What is your serial" (I don't know the exact ATA command for it) could easily be spoofed.

Comment: For completeness I am adding that disks were connected using SATA to USB adapter, as correctly stated in the answer.